# All Gradle flavors description always return last value

Tags: android, gradle, android-build-flavors

Like the following grade script setting:

```
productFlavors {
   A { description "A"}
   B { description "B" }
   C { description "C" }
    }

productFlavors.all { flavor ->
        println name
        println description
    }
```

logout is:

```
A 
C
B
C
C
C
```

What is wrong with me here?

Comment: Maybe you should use `flavor.name`, `flavor.description`?

Comment: flavor.name can pass compile,  but flavor.description cannot. So, description for what?   [Build Type + Product Flavor = Build Variant]

Comment: Seems like `productFlavor` class doesn't have the field `description`

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28232261/android-studio-gradle-product-flavors-define-custom-properties/28279105#28279105

Comment: Good point. And I know the reason of the problem. Always the puzzle is "description" is not my custom define property. My first impression is it is inline property, just like 'name' property. You can use smart tip to see it when click down 'd' the first letter in your productFlavors block.

Answer (score 1):

If your intention is to use description somewhere in your code it is better you add a `BuildConfigField`. You can do it as follows:

```
productFlavors {
   A { 
     buildConfigField 'String', 'DESCRIPTION', '"A"'
   }
   B { 
     buildConfigField 'String', 'DESCRIPTION', '"B"' 
   }
   C { 
     buildConfigField 'String', 'DESCRIPTION', '"C"'
   }
}
```

These can be accessed in your java code as follows:

```
String desc = BuildConfig.DESCRIPTION;
```

Comment: thanks. Yes, your comment is good. To me, I wonder how to use "description" property in the build.gradle for different productFlavors? You know, 'name' field can be printed with right value, but 'description'.

Comment: Haven't tried it but can you try and print "BuildConfig.DESCRIPTION" and see of it works there?

Comment: Yes, it works.  "Description" is referred to Project define: /**
     * Returns the description of this project.
     *
     * @return the description. May return null.
     */
    String getDescription();