# Specifying base for a build variant

Tags: android

Build variant is a really powerful tool for creating different variant of your codes by specifying minor difference and I largely use it in my projects. But I wonder if it is possible to select a specific variant as a base for another variant rather than `main`.

For example, lets assume my app has 3 variants: `A` (main), `B` and `C`. Variant `B` has a lot of different resource file from variant `A`, so I add them into `B` variant folder and everything goes well when I compile variant `B`. But for variant `C`, it has a very small changes based on variant `B`. Now I wonder what is the best approach for creating variant `C`. The simplest approach is to copy all changed files of `B` variant (in comparison with `A` variant) to variant `C` and apply small change to them for variant `C`. I personally don't like this approach, because I need to apply all changed to variant `B` to variant `C` too which is prone to mistakes and bugs.

Is there anyway to connect variant `C` to variant `B`, so while `aar` trying to create `C` variant's resources, it uses variant `B` as base rather than variant `A`? I think it will be possible with adding another dimension to variants, but I prefer to do this without adding new dimensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could config next `BuildType` based on other by e.g.

```
debugWithAnalytics.initWith(buildTypes.debug)
```

But you should use flavors and flavor dimensions in terms of functionality - it's possible to merge different flavors into one configuration because buildTypes mean difference in build configuration. `BuildTypes` should contain info about build proccess, e.g signconfigs, basic build flow configs etc.

```
flavorDimensions("devbeta", "mainmirror")
productFlavors {
    // Beta API enviroment
    beta {
        dimension = "devbeta"
        buildConfigField "String", "SOCKET_REMOTE_PATH", "\"/beta\""
    }

    // Dev API enviroment
    dev {
        dimension = "devbeta"
        buildConfigField "String", "SOCKET_REMOTE_PATH", "\"/dev\""
    }

    // Prod API enviroment
    prod {
        dimension = "devbeta"
        buildConfigField "String", "SOCKET_REMOTE_PATH", "\"/prod\""
    }

    mainhost {
        dimension = "mainmirror"
        buildConfigField "String", "CONFIG_REMOTE_HOSTNAME", "\"mainmirro1\""
    }

    mirrorhost {
        dimension = "mainmirror"
        buildConfigField "String", "CONFIG_REMOTE_HOSTNAME", "\"mainmirrow\""
    }
}
```

In this case possible build variants will be `...MainhostBeta` `MirrorhostDev` etc.

Comment: Hi, I wrote that I think it is possible with dimensions, but I wonder if there is another approach too or not. Because I already have a 3D dimension, I prefer another approach if possible rather than adding 4th dimension...

Comment: @Afshin you could config build type with another buildtype, check beggining of the answer, so in your case C could extend B

Comment: Yea,saw reply update. a question, when I use `initWith`, will resource directories changes to then one mentioned in `initWith` as base too?

Comment: You could define any type of source dirs as you wish: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32758837/527808 using inherited folders should not work out of the box just because you could define your own folder for each buildtype.